# Interpretation and validity of linear regression when dependent variables has negative, positive and lot of 0 values

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, linear

I am new on this site, so excuse me, if I made any mistakes writing this post.

I want the describe the results of a linear regression of a variable "cost_difference" which has some positive values, some negative values and a lot of 0 based on the variable "days".

As I'm not allowed to share further information about my data, I made a little simulation

```
> cost_difference <- c(-5,0,-6,46,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,13,-24,0,0,0,0,00,0,0,-9)
> days <- c(20,12,26,14,22,24,17,10,69,21,16,30,23,25,11,15,29,50,13,28,19)
> test <-data.table(cost_difference,days)
> plot(test$cost_difference ~ test$days, 
+      xlab = "days", 
+      ylab = "Cost difference")
> abline(lm(test$cost_difference ~ test$days))

> summary(cost_difference)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-24.000   0.000   0.000   1.095   0.000  46.000 

> my_lm <- lm(cost_difference ~days, data=test)
> summary(my_lm)

Call:
lm(formula = cost_difference ~ days, data = test)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-25.140  -2.155  -1.647  -0.632  44.099 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  3.08651    5.56115   0.555    0.585
days        -0.08465    0.20551  -0.412    0.685

Residual standard error: 12.6 on 19 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.008851,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.04331 
F-statistic: 0.1697 on 1 and 19 DF,  p-value: 0.685
```

My question:

- Can lm be used to describe the relationship between those 2 variables?
- is this method okay with so many 0 and negative values?
- is there a better model to do that?
- what does a negative t-value mean?
- what does a negative adj. R^2 mean?
- would it help to ignore the case with 0? or any methodological issues with that?
- do the results read as follows (English not my main language): starting with 3.09 ± 5.56 at day 0, for each additional day the Cost-Difference reduces by 0.085 ± 0.21

Comment: If I was analysing this data I would want to know more about how the `cost_difference` variable is generated, why many values are zero and why there are occasionally large positive and large negative values.  Without knowing how the data arose it is difficult to know what an appropriate model is.